# MySQL Trigger - Where am I going wrong

Tags: mysql, database

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong in creating this trigger in MySQL? Every time I try to create it, it keeps telling me there is an error.

```
USE `cl11-onestock`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER audit_insert
AFTER INSERT 
    ON stock_usage FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET uUid = (SELECT UUID());
    SET stockUsageId = (SELECT NEW.stock_usage_id);
    SET siteId = (SELECT NEW.site_id);
    SET date = (SELECT NEW.date);
    SET patientName = (SELECT NEW.patient_name);
    SET dentistDiscountId = (SELECT NEW.dentist_discount_id);
    SET itemId = (SELECT NEW.item_id);
    SET quantity = (SELECT NEW.quantity);
    SET priceIncDiscount = (SELECT NEW.price_inc_discount);
    SET vat = (SELECT NEW.vat);
    SET priceIncVat = (SELECT NEW.price_inc_vat);
    SET createdAt = (SELECT NEW.created_at);
    SET updatedAt = (SELECT NEW.updated_at);

    INSERT INTO stock_audit VALUES
    (uUid, stockUsageId, siteId, date, patientName, dentistDiscountId, itemId, quantity, priceIncDiscount, vat, priceIncVat, createdAt, updatedAt);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please post the error to allow people to help you.

Comment: The only thing it's not showing an error code. In the output panel it's just showing a red cross instead of a tick.

Comment: Oh wait there is an error code. It is Error Code: 1142

Comment: Error code 1142 is related to the user permission check if the user is having proper permission to perform the operations.

Comment: Minor grammar improvements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword `new` to access the field values after insert and not like you are doing with `select` and you can use directly inside the insert query

So the trigger should be as

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER audit_insert
AFTER INSERT 
    ON stock_usage FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO stock_audit VALUES
    (new.UUID, NEW.stock_usage_id, NEW.site_id, NEW.date, NEW.patient_name, NEW.dentist_discount_id, NEW.item_id, NEW.quantity, NEW.price_inc_discount, NEW.vat, NEW.price_inc_vat, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```